# How long does ceviche keep?

Tags: storage-lifetime, ceviche

We just made ceviche with ahi tuna, lots of lime juice, avocado, onion, cilantro and jalapeño. It's wonderful. Unfortunately we made too much. Now, I've never made it before and want to know about how long I should keep it in the fridge, if at all?

Note: this is not super high quality sashimi grade fish. Nor is it the freshest fish in the world.

Comment: I'm not going to answer because I don't know. The true answer will depend in part upon the freshness of the ingredients you used. But I'll say this much, I wouldn't keep ceviche in the fridge for over 48 hours.

Comment: @Jolenealaska that was kind of my gut feeling, too.

Answer (score 3):

Drain as much of the "cooking" solution (lime etc) off as possible, and store separately

Both parts will keep a day or two

After draining you can briefly rinse the fish to stop the "cooking" process, otherwise it may go a little mushy, but not unappetising

Answer (score 2):

My reading of Kenji López-Alt's [food lab on ceviche](http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/07/the-food-lab-ceviche-and-the-science-of-marin.html) is that once you marinade it you should eat it ideally within 30 minutes and certainly within 1 hour. Any longer and the texture is ruined.

Comment: I have read the same article, and I believe your interpretation to be flawed. The author of that article tested the effect of marinating the fish in straight lime juice. When you remove the fish from the marinade, the process slows down conciderably. Furthermore, the addition of salt to the marinade will likely change the PH of the liquid, which means that any time estimates given in the original article will be too low for the actual effect of the marinade.

Answer (score 2):

The acidic ingredients in the ceviche dressing will not significantly preserve or extend the quality of the tuna, but it will continue to break down the connective tissues in the fish and gradually ruin the texture.  You will also run the risk of contamination just as if you'd kept the unprepared raw fish in your fridge.  This is especially a concern if your fish wasn't very fresh (i.e. purchased the same day) to begin with.

I would keep this for no more than 48 hours at absolute maximum, depending on your tolerance for the change in texture.  Pour off as much of the marinade as possible and keep the ceviche tightly sealed.  When serving again, you can add fresh lime juice to adjust the flavor.  If you detect any fishy odor whatsoever at any time, *discard immediately*.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that the high acid content would prevent any microbes from being a problem, so I would expect ceviche to be safe over time if the marinade remains on the fish.  However, the texture do seem to be "well done" rather than fresh and tender.

Answer (score -4):

I say a round a bout a day or 2

Answer (score -4):

I have kept a week or longer.  The fresh lime juice seems to preserve it....??  Never a problem.

Comment: I would advise against suggesting such long date's, especially on fish intended to be eaten raw. The lime juice will 'cook'(http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/articles/A36202-2004Nov9.html) the fish, not preserve NOR cure. Longer than a week for fresh fish, to be cooked, is pushing it. Never mind eaten raw. Welcome to Seasoned Advice @Betty Bayne

Answer (score -4):

Suggest you all read about pickled fish and sea food.  It last for 6 months to a year.  I have kept ceveche refrigerated and eaten it weeks later.  It tastes a bit fish stronger and the texture is not as firm as the first 3 days but, it is still good. And, I am still alive and well to tell about it. If you use fresh squeezed citrus, (lemon, lime, orange) once it is cooked in the citrus acid it goes on and becomes pickled.  Ceveche was the way fish and seafood was preserved hundreds of years before there was refrigeration.  Surely, you don't think this preservation method was only for a few hours or days.